# What is the difference between Flink's bulk iteration operator and a while loop?

Tags: apache-flink

From [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/index.html#iteration-operators), I know loops can be implemented with iteration operators. Since Flink code is lazily evaluated, it is not possible to evaluate a termination condition using a while loop.

But for bulk iterations like `initial.iterate(10){...}`, can we use a while loop to achieve the same effect?

```
var dataset = ...   
while (i < 10) {
    dataset = step(dataset);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of using the built-in bulk iteration operator and constructing a plan with a while loop is the resulting execution plan.

While Loop:

```
StartDS -> Step1 -> Step2 -> ... -> Step10 -> ResultDS
```

Bulk Iteration:

```
StartDS -> IterationHead -> Step -> IterationTail -> ResultDS
               ^                           |
                \-----------(9 times)-----/
```

Depending on the number of iteration that you are running, the size of the bulk iteration plan can be significantly smaller. A smaller plan means Flink needs less time to optimize and schedule the plan.

Moreover, the optimizer can leverage the information about the explicit iteration and cache DataSets in memory that are used in each iteration.